# Change ViewController without setting navigationitem

Tags: ios, swift

I am moving between two navigationviewcontroller's via instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in swift however the latter of the two navigationcontroller's sets a back navigationitem, I do not want to do this as it is going from login to home!

does anyone know how I can disable it for this action?

```
var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainUserView") as UIViewController

self.showViewController(vc, sender: vc)
```

Comment: Show the code you're using

Answer (score 0):

What about showing the navigation controller that has login viewcontroller as its root modally over home viewcontroller ? 
If you won't need to show another viewcontroller from login like registration, you can present it modally without embedding it in navigation controller.

For Example, I do this in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"homeNavigationController"]; // the navigation Controller that has HomeViewController as its root

[self.window setRootViewController: homeNavigationController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

if (![User isUserRegistered]) { //if user is not registered show login screens
    UIViewController *introNavigationController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"IntroNavigationController"];  // the navigation Controller that has LoginViewController as its root
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:introNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need back home and disappear back Button  you can write some words at login class

```
   `//let backButton disappear
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = ""`
```